# mysqli fetch_assoc() not returning

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a webservice which i have developed in PHP using SLIM on my private WAMP server, where everything works fine. When deploying it to my webhotel, msqli fetch_assoc seems to never return and i get a "Response does not contain any data." I confirmed that it never returned by first putting and echo before the fetch_assoc call .. and afterward after the call .. and it never hit my echo when put after fetch_assoc.

My private webserver runs PHP 5.4.12 and MySQL 5.6.12, whereas my webhotel is running PHP 5.3.28 and MYSQL 5.1.71.

Is it my web host that need to upgrade their mysql server, as i have learned that this has been an issue in some mysql server versions ?

In desperate need of help ... Thanks

EDIT 1:

```
public function getUserByEmail($email) {

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT name, email, api_key, status, created_at FROM user WHERE email = ?");

    $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
    if ($stmt->execute()) {     

    //$user = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  echo "afas";  
        $user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
        $stmt->close();
        return $user; 
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the fresh database have any records to retrieve yet?

Comment: Yes .. I exported the database from my own webserver and imported it on my web hotel.

Comment: I also tried the "old" way, with mysql_fetch_assoc which worked as expected...

Comment: `$stmt->execute()` Is non-false is the query completes successfully, including the case where no rows are actually returned. `$user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();` assumes that the query returned at least one row. Did it? Will it do so 100% of the time? I suggest re-writing this line to verify if any results are returned before attempting to access them.

Comment: fair enough ... i have made a field_count on the result.. this revealed that get_result never returned ..

Comment: Do you have error reporting turned up and displaying on screen?  [`get_result()` is only available on some systems](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php) having the mysqlnd driver.  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` _always_ when developing code.

Comment: If your production machine doesn't have `get_result()` via mysqlnd, you will need to do a `bind_result()` instead.

Comment: http://www.tjeklet.dk/TjekLetService/test.php will run a phpinfo .. i fear that mysqlnd is not present at on my web host, as they are still running php 5.3.28 .. could that be the problem ? .. please feel free to check the phpinfo with the supplied link :)

Comment: added the error reporting .. and got the following:

Fatal error</b>:  Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() in <b>/var/www/web/web667567/tjeklet.dk/TjekLetService/include/DbHandler.php

Which explains why it is not working .. seems like they need to install mysqlnd for me to proceed :) ..

Never knew i could turn on error reporting. ... big thanks for that information ;-)

Comment: now for the last question .. how do i choose the answer to my question, to close this question ? :-|

Comment: Michael Berkowski please post the error reporting comment as your answer, as it lead me to why it was not working. That way i can mark this question as answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Michael Berkowski kindly pointed me in the direction of the answer to my problem.

"get_result() is only available on some systems having the mysqlnd driver."

So i ended up switching to PDO, which did not require a lot of changes to my code..

Answer (score 1):

Check your phpinfo(). I have mysqlnd, but only the PDO exension. You can tell by looking a the API Extensions under the mysqlnd section (if mysqlnd is installed).

Instead of re-writing everything in PDO, this worked for me:

```
public function getUserByEmail($email) {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT name, email, api_key, status, created_at FROM users WHERE email = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        $stmt->bind_result($name, $email, $api_key, $status, $created_at);

        /* fetch values */
        mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);

        /* set values */
        $user['name'] = $name;
        $user['email'] = $email;
        $user['api_key'] = $api_key;
        $user['created_at'] = $created_at;

        $stmt->close();
        return $user;
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```