# I keep getting error on fetch_assoc() in PHP

Tags: php, android

I am trying to create a login/register feature on my android app. One of my files contains a two functions that are being used by register and login. I keep getting an error, the same error when I try to do both. I am getting this error from my *error_log* file and I have tried google for a while now and can't seem to find a solution to my particular issue. The error I get is:

*Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in DB_Functions.php*

and the parts I get the error are here:

Login:

```
public function getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password) {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);

    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        $user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();        <----THIS LINE
        $stmt->close();
        return $user;
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

Register:

```
if ($result) {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
    $stmt->execute();
    $user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();          <----AND THIS LINE
    $stmt->close();

    return $user;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: *"If your production machine doesn't have get_result() via mysqlnd, you will need to do a [`bind_result()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php) instead. – Michael Berkowski Mar 19 '14 at 22:22"*

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysqli fetch_assoc() not returning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22518533/mysqli-fetch-assoc-not-returning)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Hi, I tried replacing get_result() with bind_result() but it gives me the same error.

Comment: then this could be a variable scope issue. Try running your code without the custom function. If it works, then you'll know what to go after. and bind_result() works like this `$stmt->bind_result($col1, $col2);` you can't just place that function with nothing else in it. RTM http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php

Comment: non-object can also mean many other possible reasons. Wrong database/table, variable for email not being populated, a mix of some or all. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.